# Binomial coefficient; substitution?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

How do we get this equality?

\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n+l-1}{l}q^l=\binom{-n}{l}(-q)^l
\end{eqnarray*}

I haven't worked a lot with the binomial coefficient, so I don't really have a feel for these things... I really hope someone would help me with this, even though I haven't shown what I've tried, because I haven't been able to come up with much.

Comment: how did you get the coefficient of n negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why, that's simple.
$$\binom{n+l-1}{l}={\overbrace{(n+l-1)(n+l-2)\dots n}^{\color{red}{l\;terms}}\over l!}$$
On the other hand,
$$\binom{-n}{l}={\overbrace{(-n)(-n-1)\dots(-n-l+1)}^{\color{red}{l\;terms}}\over l!}={n(n+1)\dots(n+l-1)\over l!}\cdot(-1)^l$$

Comment: It is one of the basic binomial identity, called "Upper Negation"

Comment: Oh, I had completely forgotten to write it out as a quotient with factorials. Thank you a lot for your help.